# Is it possible to set the window title of my console app without setting Console.Title?

Tags: .net, console-application

When my console app first runs, I execute `Console.Title = "whatever"` to change the window's title.  What bugs me is that there is that split second where the console window's title is the path to the EXE itself.  I'd like to think that there's a way to set the title so that it's stored in the application settings itself so that I don't have to set it with code.

Comment: well, until the application is ran, how would windows know which title to display ? To run your console application, the first thing windows has to do is run the console... that's when you see the path to your application

Comment: @Bartdude That is my question.  In a WinForms app, you can set the title of a form in the properties.  I know this is a console app and not a WinForms app, but I was wondering if something similar existed with console apps, if not a hack that I could implement in the project's raw XML.

Comment: It is fairly inevitable that eventually every programmer gets annoyed at the limitations of a console window.  If their client got them there first.  There are many, this is just another one.  They progress to creating their own.  It takes a Winforms or WPF project.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps run it as with a batch file called "my_console_app.bat"?

```
start "My display name" my_console_app.exe
```