# Renaming console windows while debugging

Tags: windows, visual-studio, .net-core

For a Net Core 2.1 application with output type "Console Application" started from Visual Studio debug mode, I would like to give that console windows a name instead of C:....\dotnet.exe

( due to the need to start multiple projects at once )

[image]

How can this be achieved?

To clarify why my question was different from the others:

I am trying to start a console project from Visual Studio's Debug mode. I would prefer not to change the source code. It would be best to have the windows name set through a **project property** or a specific **VS debug configuration**. The referenced posts do not care about starting into Visual Studio Debug at all

This is needed because when we start 4-5 projects in debug configuration and look at the console for the recent logs, Its impossible to know which console windows is started from which VS instance. I would not care about release configuration at all and prefer to keep the release console application using the default process/windows name due to fear that setting the application name could have some unpredicted issue with serverless hosting.

Comment: Does anything [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B.net%5D++console+title) help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to set the window title of my console app without setting Console.Title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17343001/is-it-possible-to-set-the-window-title-of-my-console-app-without-setting-console)

Comment: I am trying to start from Visual Studio 's Debug mode
I would prefer not to change the source code. The referenced post do not care about starting into Visual Studio Debug at all

Comment: It would have been helpful if you included the additional details in your initial post. It would have saved at least @Thangadurai and me some time looking to try to find an answer to the original version of your post. You may want to consider that for future questions. :-)

Comment: Thank you. I updated the additional information. The referenced post was helpful also